# Chart disappears, but it shows when I press f12 (?)

Tags: angular, charts, angular-services, angular-chart, angular-chartist.js

I use chart.js and I load data with service from db.
After reloading it's not shown, but when I press f12 to open the console it appears like nothing happened.

component ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartData } from 'chart.js';
import { IInventory } from 'src/app/models/inventory';
import { IStorage } from 'src/app/models/storage';
import { InventoryService } from 'src/app/services/inventory.service';
import { StorageService } from 'src/app/services/storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stocks-chart',
  templateUrl: './stocks-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stocks-chart.component.scss']
})
export class StocksChartComponent {

  stocks: IInventory[]
  storages: IStorage[]
  selectedStorage: string = ''
  stocksData: ChartData<'doughnut'> = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      { data: [] }
    ]
  }
  stocksLabels: string[]
  
  constructor(inventory: InventoryService, storages: StorageService) {
    inventory.getInventory().subscribe((res: IInventory[]) => {
      this.stocks = res
      res.map((item: IInventory) => {
        if (this.stocksData.labels?.includes(item.productName)) {
          this.stocksData.datasets[0].data[this.stocksData.labels.indexOf(item.productName)] += item.stock
        } else {
          this.stocksData.labels?.push(item.productName)
          this.stocksData.datasets[0].data.push(item.stock)
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

html:

```
<canvas
                baseChart
                type="doughnut"
                [data]="stocksData"
            ></canvas>
```

I don't know, maybe there's something because it draws before getting data. But anyway, why does it appear after the window resizes (and the chart is still showing even after I close the console)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with different chart. I solved it with different solutions.
1.in your chart component call `onWidthResize`;
2.updateing chart size with `updateSize()` method (for me this method was in zoomcharts)

```
 @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])   onWidthResize(e: any) {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.innerHeight = window.innerHeight;   }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.onWidthResize(null);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.myChart.updateSize()
      }, 500)
  }
```